# How to add Kotlin to an existing Java project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I want to dip a toe into Kotlin by converting just a few classes in a Java project into Kotlin.

A Google search for "how to add kotlin to existing eclipse project" turns up several tutorials on:

- How to start a *new* Kotlin project in Eclipse
- How to add Kotlin to an existing Java project in *IntelliJ*

How can I **add Kotlin** to an **existing Java** project in **Eclipse**?

Assume the project is already Maven 3.x and Java 8 compliant.

Comment: Especially since you're new to Kotlin, I would encourage to to simply create an all-Kotlin project.  At least for starters...

Comment: @paulsm4 Kotlin is useless to me if it cannot seamlessly integrate into an existing Java project in Eclipse, so I don't see the point of trying it by itself.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html. At the bottom of link, there is an example `mvn`+`java`+`kotlin`.

Comment: Groovy language integration in Eclipse provides this ability and has many of the same advantages of Kotlin and other advantages that Kotlin lacks.

Comment: @adnbsr your article does not touch on Eclipse at all

Comment: @emiles the question is about Kotlin, not Groovy. Please explain what is the relevance of Groovy in this context?

Comment: The relevance is that Kotlin is not capable of what you are asking within Eclipse. Groovy provides that capability so it is a close substitute.

Comment: As I understand it, Kotlin can be used in the same project as Java but not in the same source folder. So you could add a src/main/kotlin to your project and move a few Java sources to it and rename them from ".java" to ".kt". But you will need to be sure these sources don't depend on any of your Java sources or vice versa.

Comment: @emilles Thanks for the clarification. Switching to Groovy would be worse than switching to IntelliJ.

Comment: You can do some of what you're asking for in Eclipse. But you either have dependency constraints or you have to ditch Eclipse compiler and rely on Gradle or Maven for building (which is what IntelliJ is doing).

Comment: @emilles your comment "Kotlin can be used in the same project as Java but not in the same source folder" is probably the best answer, if you care to elaborate...

Comment: @AlexR The Kotlin compiler is not a joint compiler, meaning it does not process both Java and Kotlin sources. Therefore you need to run Kotlin compiler first and then Java compiler after. Or reverse the two. This means the dependencies can work in one direction only without some more advanced steps like interfaces and dependency injection.

Comment: You can search "kotlin java joint compilation" on the web for more information on this and some strategies for project layout. I mention Groovy because it does offer joint compilation so you can have both types of sources in the same source folder and dependencies in both directions.

Comment: Many years ago we found that netBeans was much better at handling Ruby than Eclipse, so perhaps using a different IDE might be a solution, all be it for the short term